# Maven : Unable to parse maven.config file options: Unrecognized option: -am -gt toolchains.xml

Tags: java, macos, maven

I have been trying to execute basic Maven command after importing project into intellij on Mac.
I am not trying to run the project. When I try to run the command : mvn --version I get this message with a huge list of options. Not sure, what is causing this behaviour.

```
aravind.s@A2141-TI13169-B recopp % mvn --version
Unable to parse maven.config file options: Unrecognized option: -am -gt toolchains.xml

usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
```

Contents of the maven config file just contains this :

-am -gt toolchains.xml

And toolchains.xml contains this :

```
<toolchains>
    <toolchain>
        <type>jdk</type>
        <provides>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </provides>
        <configuration>
            <!-- set the env JAVA_HOME to jdk8 before mvn package  -->
            <jdkHome>${env.JAVA_HOME}</jdkHome>
        </configuration>
    </toolchain>
    <toolchain>
        <type>jdk</type>
        <provides>
            <version>11</version>
        </provides>
        <configuration>
            <!-- set the env JAVA_HOME to jdk11 before mvn package  -->
            <jdkHome>${env.JAVA_HOME}</jdkHome>
        </configuration>
    </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

and java version is 1.8.

Will be glad to receive any inputs regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the content of `maven.config` file here?

Comment: Added just now.

Comment: Use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.

Comment: That's not the content of the `maven.config` file... Why using `env.JAVA_HOME` in your toolchains.xml file that does not make sense.. it's easier to use only `JAVA_HOME` via `sdkmain.io` or alike instead of indirecting via toolchains.xml ...?

Comment: I am not sure. I am still trying to get the entire picture here. I have never come across the file like toolchains.xml so far. Is it okay if I gave the actual Java path itself?

Answer (score 3):

From https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.2/release-notes.html

Starting from Maven 3.9.x - Each line in `.mvn/maven.config` is now interpreted as a single argument.

So your `.mvn/maven.config` should be like:

```
-am
-gt
toolchains.xml
```